# Strange "Missing Index" suggestion from MS-SQL-Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

The SSMS Execution Plan gives the error message "Missing Index" and recommends that I create a long index consisting of 10 fields:

[image]

Does it really make sense to create such a long index?

The index suggestion also contains all numerical value fields.
I never access the table via the numeric fields.

Comment: 10 **columns** really isn't take many, especially when they are in `INCLUDE`. Often you *want* an index to be covering, as it means that a key lookup isn't required. Of course, this isn't me saying that the index suggestion is correct. Those missing index recommendations should always be taken with a pinch of salt and with testing.

Comment: Also note: Missing indexes are recommendations from the execution plan, not errors.

Comment: Definitely take it withe a pinch of salt, it just means that there is probably *some* combination of index columns and include columns that will help, not necessarily the one it's given: see https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/08/missing-index-recommendations-arent-perfect/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms345485(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN **Please share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com and maybe we can help you create a better index**

Comment: By the way, I hope you know what the table names and columns mean, because I doubt anyone else does. Use short, clear names for tables and columns, not unreadable, capitalized acronyms

Comment: I prefer to call missing indexes suggestions rather than recommendations. A human being needs to do a sanity check, especially when a large number of included columns are suggested.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers. You can find the query plan in this thread: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66330972/ms-sql-server-2019-is-slower-than-2008-for-some-sql-selects?noredirect=1#comment117288661_66330972
It's the same problem and the same tables and the same query.

Answer (score 0):

There si only 1 column in the index key. Which is very light.

There is almost 10 columns in the include clause of the suggested index.

To be efficient, indexing only the seeked columns (SPTAG in your case) is not systematically a good choice, because the database engine needs to access to 2 data structures :

1. first read (seek in the index) to find candidate rows that are qualified under the predicate
2. second read in the table to find the columns that the index does not have

But if the index got all the columns needed for every clauses of the query (SELECT, JOIN/ON, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, ORDER BY) there will be only one datastructure used to give your complete results dataset.

The cost of the two reads is compare, by the optimizer, to the cost of other strategies like scanning the table. If the cost of the scan is lower, the index won't be used...
So the recommanded strategy for the given index is to have all data inside it !

Comment: Thanks for the info, but what exactly do I have to do now? Should I create the index with the 10 columns?

Comment: @SipCat To gain only about 8% of speed and make writes slower? I don't think that you should make such index - but like always, you need to play with real data and compare actual query times.

Comment: The 8 indice (not shure that is a %) is only an estimation. The best way is to get the cost of the plan and the IO/time stats before and after having create this index.

Comment: 10 columns can be stupid if the table has only 11 columns? But it is interesting if the table has more than 30 columns....